# Subgroups of General Linear Group

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

I have a question about the order of the subgroups of $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ generated by the following matrix:

$\begin{pmatrix}
 1&-1 \\ 
 -1&0 
\end{pmatrix}$

So I computed several powers of this matrix and realized that the order of the subgroup generated by this matrix is infinity. However, I do not know how to prove it in general that:

${\begin{pmatrix}
 1&-1 \\ 
 -1&0 
\end{pmatrix}}^n\neq \begin{pmatrix}
 1&0 \\ 
 0&1 
\end{pmatrix} \forall n\in\mathbb{Z}.$

Is there any way to prove this in general? I might have did not remember something from Linear Algebra to prove this. Any suggestion is really appreciated.

Here are what I got for my calculations:

${\begin{pmatrix}
 1&-1 \\ 
 -1&0 
\end{pmatrix}}^2= \begin{pmatrix}
 2&-1 \\ 
 -1&1 
\end{pmatrix} $

${\begin{pmatrix}
 1&-1 \\ 
 -1&0 
\end{pmatrix}}^3= \begin{pmatrix}
 3&-2 \\ 
 -2&1 
\end{pmatrix} $

${\begin{pmatrix}
 1&-1 \\ 
 -1&0 
\end{pmatrix}}^4= \begin{pmatrix}
 5&-3 \\ 
 -3&2 
\end{pmatrix} $

${\begin{pmatrix}
 1&-1 \\ 
 -1&0 
\end{pmatrix}}^5= \begin{pmatrix}
 8&-5 \\ 
 -5&3 
\end{pmatrix} $

${\begin{pmatrix}
 1&-1 \\ 
 -1&0 
\end{pmatrix}}^6= \begin{pmatrix}
 13&-8 \\ 
 -8&5 
\end{pmatrix} $

Comment: If you look carefully at the powers you calculated, perhaps you can see a pattern.  If you post them as part of your question, perhaps someone can make a suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: When you diagonalize this matrix, you get 
$
S\begin{pmatrix} \frac{-1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2} \end{pmatrix}S^{-1}$

for some ugly matrices $S$ and $S^{-1}$. These numbers are larger in norm than $1$.

Comment: These numbers are larger in norm than $1$ , then  what does it mean ?

Comment: Okay, I remembered things about diagonalize but couldn't remember or even recall the case when these numbers are larger in norm than 1, is there any documents or text that I can read about this. Sorry but I haven't touched Linear Algebra for 2 years so I couldn't recall it.

Comment: I could have just said 'absolute value.' The idea being that if you take powers of this expansion, the diagonal coefficients will grow, and are already at least 1.

Comment: For example, calling this matrix $M$, we have $M^2 = SDS^{-1}SDS^{-1} = SD^2S^{-1}$, and so you can see what's happening to the diagonal entries. They are getting larger and larger in absolute value, so they cannot possibly ever be $1$.

Comment: Oh, I think I got it now. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of a matrix $A$ (that is, there exists a nonzero column vector $v$ such that $Av = \lambda v$), then $\lambda^n$ is an eigenvalue of the matrix $A^n$.

Suppose that $A^n = I$ for some $n$.  What are the eigenvalues of $I$?

Comment: I see. Thank you so much.